# Function that returns the length of the longest run of repetition in a given list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to write a function that returns the length of the longest run of repetition in a given list

Here is my code:

```
def longest_repetition(a):
  longest = 0
  j = 0
  run2 = 0
  while j <= len(a)-1:
    for i in a:
      run = a.count(a[j] == i)
      if run == 1:
          run2 += 1
    if run2 > longest:
        longest = run2
    j += 1
    run2 = 0
  return longest

print(longest_repetition([4,1,2,4,7,9,4]))
print(longest_repetition([5,3,5,6,9,4,4,4,4]))

3
0
```

The first test function works fine, but the second test function is not counting at all and I'm not sure why. Any insight is much appreciated

Just noticed that the question I was given and the expected results are not consistent. So what I'm basically trying to do is find the most repeated element in a list and the output would be the number of times it is repeated. That said, the output for the second test function should be 4 because the element '4' is repeated four times (elements are not required to be in one run as implied in my original question)

Comment: explain what do you mean my longest run of repetition ? are you asking about frequency ?

Comment: Just noticed that the question I was given and the expected results are not consistent. So what I'm basically trying to do is find the most repeated element in a list and the output would be the number of times it is repeated. That said, the output for the second test function should be 4 because the element '4' is repeated four times (elements are not required to be in one run as implied in my original question)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's check if you were consistent with your question (function that returns the length of the longest run of repetition):
e.g.:

a = [4,1,2,4,7,9,4]

b = [5,3,5,6,9,4,4,4,4]

(assuming, you are only checking single position, e.g. c = [1,2,3,1,2,3] could have one repetition of sequence 1,2,3 - i am assuming that is not your goal)

So:

for *a*, there is no repetitions of same value, therefore length equals **0**

for *b*, you have one, quadruple repetition of *4*, therefore length equals **4**

First, your `max_amount_of_repetitions=0` and `current_repetitions_run=0' So, what you need to do to detect repetition is simply check if value of` n-1`'th and` n`'th element is same. If so, you increment` current_repetitions_run', else, you reset `current_repetitions_run=0`.
Last step is check if your current run is longest of all:

`max_amount_of_repetitions= max(max_amount_of_repetitions, current_repetitions_run)`

to surely get both *n-1* and *n* within your list range, I'd simply start iteration from second element. That way, *n-1* is first element.

```
for n in range(1,len(a)):
    if a[n-1] == a[n]:
       print("I am sure, you can figure out the rest")
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply. Ur right my question is not consistent with my code so let me clarify. I'm basically trying to  find the most repeated element in a list and the output would be the number of times it is repeated. That said, the output for the second test function should be 4 because the element '4' is repeated four times (elements are not required to be in one run as implied in my original question), but Im getting 0 instead

Comment: then, I'd probably go with dictionary, where you save occurrences of each individual value, e.g. for 'a', dict results['a'] = results['a']+1. At the end, you can search dict for highest value, and even get the letter that was most common in your input

Answer (score 0):

you can use `hash` to calculate the frequency of the element and then get the max of frequencies.

using functional approach

```
from collections import Counter
def longest_repitition(array):
    return max(Counter(array).values())
```

other way, without using Counter

```
def longest_repitition(array):
    freq = {}
    for val in array:
        if val not in freq:
            freq[val] = 0
        freq[val] += 1
    values = freq.values()
    return max(values)
```